# Does this make sense what I have written? Prooving that $\{|x|,|y|\}$ is a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

I tried to proove the following in the last post

> Show that the norm $||(x,y)||=max\{|x|,|y|\}$ where ||.|| is the norm and $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ really is a norm by verifiying all the Axioms.

But they baisically told me that it is a horrible mess and my tutor is complaing generally about the clearaty of my Proofs. Is this version better?

Let $v$ denote a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x$,$y$ are the two components.

First we need to show that
$||v||=0$ $\iff$ $v=0$

We use $A \Rightarrow B \land B \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow (A \iff B)$ in order to do this

Consider first $\Rightarrow$:

We have $||v||=||(x,y)||=max\{|x|,|y|\}=0$ This implies that $|x| \leq 0$ and $|y| \leq 0$ which implies since $0 \leq |x| \leq 0$ and $0 \leq |y| \leq 0$ that $x=0$ and $y=0$. Thus we have $v=0$ where $v=(x,y)$.

the other direction $ \Leftarrow$

Let $v=0$ then $x=0$ $y=0$. We find that $||v||=0$ since the maximum of two zeros is oviously zero.

The second we need to show is that $||\lambda v||=\lambda ||v||$ where $\lambda$ is a real number.

We now try to show that $||\lambda v||=|\lambda| ||v||$

We have that $max\{|\lambda x|,|\lambda y|\}=max\{|\lambda||y|,|\lambda||y|\}$

Let wlog $|\lambda||x|$ be the maximum of $|\lambda||x|$ and $|\lambda||y|$ meaning $|x||\lambda|\leq |x||\lambda|$ and $|y||\lambda|\leq |\lambda||x|$. It is easy to see that by dividing by $\lambda$ we have $|x|\leq |x|$ and $|y| \leq |x|$ thus we find $max\{|x|,|y|\}=|x|$. But then we have $||v||=max\{|\lambda x|, |\lambda y|\}=max\{|\lambda||x|,|\lambda||y|\}=|\lambda||x|=|\lambda|max\{|x|,|y|\}$ and finally we can conclude that $||\lambda v||=|\lambda|||v||$

The third and last Axiom we need to show is that $||v+w||\leq||v||+||w||$ where $w$ simply denotes another vector. And let $v=(x_1,y_1)$ and let $w=(x_2,y_2)$.

Let wlog be $|x_1+x_2|$ the maximum of $|x_1+x_2|$,$|y_1+y_2|$ then we find that $|y_1+y_2| \leq |x_1+x_2|\leq |x_1|+|x_2|$ und thus $|x_1|+|x_2|$ is greater than the maximum of $|y_1+y_2|$ and $|x_1+x_2|$ and it follows

$max\{|y_1+y_2|,|x_1+x_2|\} \leq max\{|x_1|+|x_2|,|y_1|+|y_2|\}$

Let $m=max\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}$ and $m'=max\{|x_2|,|y_2|\}$ and then it is that $|x_1|+|x_2| \leq m + |x_2|$ because if $m=|x_1|$ then it is clear and if $m=|y_1|$ we have $|x_1| \leq |y_1|$ and we conclude $|x_1|+|x_2| \leq |y_1|+|x_2|=m+|x_2|$. We can apply this principle three more times and we have that

it is $|x_1|+|x_2| \leq m + |x_2| \leq m+m'$ and we also have $|y_1|+|y_2| \leq m + |y_2|\leq m+m'$ or in other words we find that

$max\{|x_1|+|x_2|,|y_1|+|y_2|\} \leq max\{|x_1|,|y_1|\}+max\{|x_2|,|y_2|\}$

So we finally find

$||v+w|| = max \{ |y_1+y_2|,|x_1+x_2|\} \leq max\{|x_1|+|x_2|,|y_1|+|y_2|\} \leq max\{
|x_1|,|y_1|\}+max\{|x_2|,|y_2|\}=||v||+||w||$

Thus we are done the norm is really a norm

Comment: Yeah this proof is very convoluted and lacks clarity. Defining $m$ and saying repeat 3 more time is just unnecessary.

Comment: Still rubbush lol :(. How can I unravel the whole thing?

Comment: The words are *proof* (name) and *prove* (verb), so both “proofing” and “prooving” are wrong.

Comment: I think you need to understand what you’re proving a bit better perhaps. Normally it should make sense in your head and it’s just a case of formalising your thought process.

Comment: For example for the triangle in equality you have $||x+y||=\max _i (|x_i+y_i|) \leq \max _i (|x_i|+|y_i| ) \leq \max _i |x_i| + \max _i |y_i| = ||x|| +||y|| $.

Comment: yes, the problem is that with such short, tight proofs my teacher thinks that i miss too many steps that is why i have written so much on purpose. or at least that's how I understood my teacher

Comment: For example I think I also have to reason why $max(|x_i+y_i|) \leq max(|x_i|+|y_i|)$ exactly is the case. But I really like the answer provided below because it is not just shorter everything is prooved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is still too complicated and verbose. I don't mean it's wrong, but it would be a very hard time reading it.

Check your attempt with the following. Writing clearer proofs requires time and effort, but don't be afraid.

---

Let's define $\|(x,y)\|=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$. We want to show that this defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We note first that, given $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have $|x|\le\|(x,y)\|$ and $|y|\le\|(x,y)\|$.

**Step 0.** We observe that $\|(x,y)\|\ge0$, because $|x|\ge0$ and $|y|\ge0$. (Note: did you observe it?)

**Step 1.** Next we'll show that $\|(x,y)\|=0$ if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$. One direction is obvious, because $\max\{|0|,|0|\}=0$. For the other direction, if $\max\{|x|,|y|\}=0$, then both $|x|\le0$ and $|y|=0$, so $|x|=|y|=0$ and finally $x=y=0$.

**Step 2.** We want now to prove that $\|\lambda(x,y)\|=|\lambda|\,\|(x,y)\|$. Since $\lambda(x,y)=(\lambda x,\lambda y)$, we have
$$
\|\lambda(x,y)\|=\max\{|\lambda x|,|\lambda y|\}
=\max\{|\lambda|\,|x|,|\lambda|\,|y|\}
$$
If $|x|\le|y|$, then $|\lambda|\,|x|\le|\lambda|\,|y|$ and similarly if $|x|\ge|y|$. Hence
$$
\max\{|\lambda|\,|x|,|\lambda|\,|y|\}=|\lambda|\max\{|x|,|y|\}=|\lambda|\,\|(x,y)\|
$$

**Step 3.** For the triangle inequality, consider $v=(x_1,y_1)$ and $w=(x_2,y_2)$. We want to prove that $\|v+w\|\le\|v\|+\|w\|$.

By the standard triangle inequality we have
$$
|x_1+x_2|\le |x_1|+|x_2|\le \|v\|+\|w\|
\qquad
|y_1+y_2|\le |y_1|+|y_2|\le \|v\|+\|w\|
$$
because of the initial remark.

Therefore
$$
\|v+w\|=\max\{|x_1+x_2|,|y_1+y_2|\}\le\|v\|+\|w\|
$$

Comment: Ty this looks way better than my version. Reading proofs and writing them down are two diffrent things.

Comment: @Iwan5050 Yes, it takes time to develop a more concise style.